# Rails fields_for :child_index option explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to create a complex form with many nested models, and make it dynamic. Now I found that making a nested model isn't difficult with accepts_nested_attributes_for, but making it nested and dynamic was seemingly impossible if there were multiple nested models.

I came across http://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb which does it very elegantly. Could anyone shed some light on lines 13 and 16?

```
13 form_builder.object.class.reflect_on_association(method).klass.new
```

and

```
16 form_builder.fields_for(method, options[:object], :child_index => "new_#{method}") do |f|
```

From intuition, line 13 instantiates a new object, but why must it do so many method calls? I couldn't find any documentation for the :child_index option on line 16. When the form is created, a very large number is used as an index for new models, whereas existing models are indexed by their id. How does this work?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
options[:object] ||= form_builder.object.class.reflect_on_association(method).klass.new
```

If the object is not passed as a parameter, it creates a new object of the corresponding class.

`form_builder.object` gets the main object from the form (`project`)

`form_builder.object.class` gets its class (`Project`)

`method` is the association name for the Project (`:tasks`)

[reflect_on_association(method)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflect_on_association) gives [AssociationReflection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection) object.

reflect_on_association(method).[klass](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/klass) returns the class of the association. (`Task`)

And, finally, klass.new creates a new instance (`Task.new` => new task)

It is done this way because the association name is not always just a pluralized class name like in this case (Task - :tasks), but it is necessary to get the class object to create new instance of it.

```
form_builder.fields_for(method, options[:object], :child_index => "new_#{method}") do |f|
```

`:child_index` option allows you to specify the index of particular object:

```
project[tasks_attributes][:child_index][field_name]
```

It is set to `"new_#{method}" by Rails, but is then replaced by javascript (application.js):

```
function insert_fields(link, method, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + method, "g")
  $(link).up().insert({
    before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
  });
}
```

Index is set to a large number just not to conflict with existing items. They are not indexed by id by the way, just from 0 to count-1

Comment: How does Rails know what to delete in the database if it's indexed from 0 to count - 1? I'm missing something.

Comment: It inserts hidden field for each record, containing it's id: `<input id="project_tasks_attributes_0_id" name="project[tasks_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="1" />`. It's a good idea to view HTML source to understand, what Rails generates.

Comment: @Voyta so it have id for the html part and id for the rails object right?