# Empty link_to_add_association for cocoon nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, cocoon-gem

I'm using simple_form with cocoon (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) and everything works pretty well.

The only thing I really really dislike is the fact that I have to initialize empty instances to make it work:

```
def new
  @facility = Facility.friendly.find(params[:facility_slug])
  @pet = @facility.pets.build(animal: Dog.new)
  @pet.pet_pictures.build
  @pet.animal.mixtures.build
end
```

The last 2 lines are for making cocoon and link_to_add_association work, if I remove them link_to_add_association is completely empty.

Does anybody know how to make this a little bit more idiomatic and avoid explicitly call the build method? How can I improve this code?

Comment: What do you mean `link_to_add_association` is empty? I've used cocoon and never had to do build the items to get it to work.  What is in the model code with associations and the view code?

Comment: It's pretty strange actually, I agree: basically it doesn't output anything. You can confirm that you were creating the records from scratch and not adding associations to something that was already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I improve this code?

By putting the code in the model:

```
#app/models/facility.rb
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
   def construct_pet animal
      model = animal.to_s.constantize
      pet = pets.build animal: model.send(:new)
      pet.pet_pictures.build
      pet.animal_mixtures.build
      pet
   end
end

#app/controllers/facilities_controller.rb
class FacilitiesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @facility = Facility.find(params[:facility_slug]).construct_pet(:dog)
   end
end
```

The problem you have is not with cocoon, it's Rails.

Let me explain:

---

**fields_for**

You must remember that rails is *object orientated*, in every sense of the term.

This means that if you want to create dependent data (IE nested fields), you'll have to build the relevant associated model instances.

There is no getting around this; if you don't build the models, Rails will simply not know how to construct the `fields_for` methods.

When you create an associated model (IE pass data with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`), Rails has to have instances of the related models to pass.

If you don't build the dependent models, you don't get any related fields, and thus it won't work.

[**Cocoon** uses `fields_for`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#how-it-works) in exactly the same way as you would if you "manually" did it:

[image]

You can see from this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [this answer I literally just wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984498/rails-4-adding-removing-form-fields-with-multiple-models/32987860#32987860).

--

> avoid explicitly call the build method

N'est pas possible, mon ami.

The `build` method creates instances of the instances associative models. If you don't want them to show (which is required to get `fields_for` working), you won't be able to use them.