# nested_form shows extra fields after error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, simple-form-for

I'm using `simple_nested_form_for` to build a form with nested fields. Fields are added dynamically

When rendering the form with errors (via `create`) the nested fields go wrong.

The same nested fields are shown multiple times and with the wrong index values in the `name` elements.

For example the `FormBuilder` `index` in the nested field is initially a random number such as `1454793731550`. After re-rendering they simply become  normal increments `0-n`.

Why is the `FormBuilder` `index` initially a random number?

Any suggestion what could be going on here?

```
  def new
    @transaction = current_company.transactions.build
    @transaction.subtransactions.build
  end

  def create
    @transaction = current_company.transactions.new(transaction_params)

    if @transaction.save
      redirect_to dashboard_url
    else
      @transaction.subtransactions.build
       render :action => 'new'
    end
```

Comment: You're going to need to post the code from your view before anybody can provide any useful insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` is the [`child_index`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879208/rails-fields-for-child-index-option-explanation) of the nested fields. This is simply a way for Rails to individually identify the various field names of the HTML form elements:

```
<%= f.fields_for :association do |a| %>
  <%= a.text_field :x %> #-> "child_index" id will either be sequential (0,1,2)
<% end %>
```

The `child_index` doesn't matter. As long as it's unique, it should be passed to the controller as follows:

```
params: {
  association_attributes: {
    0: { x: "y", z: "0" },
    1: { ... }
  }
}
```

A trick often used is to set the `child_index` to `Time.now.to_i`, which allows you to add new fields out of scope:

```
<%= f.fields_for :association, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |a| %>
```

---

In regards your `new` action with the likely issue is that your `subtransactions` object is being built each time (irrespective of whether the instance is populated with previous data).

We've had this issue before, and I *believe* that we solved it with a conditional:

```
def new
  @transaction = current_company.transactions.build
  @transaction.subtransactions.build unless @transaction.errors.any?
```

This should maintain the object's integrity through the submission process. IE if an error occurs, I believe Rails stores the associated object in memory (like it does with the parent).

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for explaining to me about the `child-index` to `Time.now.to_s`. Very useful! Adding `unless @transaction.errors.any?`  to my `new` action seems to have fixed the problem. Conceptually, however I do not get this. Why does a conditional statement about errors in the new action influence what is executed after submission through `create`?